# Selenium Webdriver : How to navigate to child div and move foucs over specific div

Tags: java, selenium

Currently facing the issue in navigating to many div tags.
In my application, I have a grid which populates or load data in multiple div tags.

On mouseover, I have to click add comment option which gets loaded as lightbox popup.

Please guide me how to select add comment option.

```
 <div ng-cell="">
<div class="inCell ng-scope">
<div class="cellDarkGray" ng2-class="{cellDarkGray: (row.getProperty('returnedRecordsNumber') != '0'),cellDarkGray: (row.getProperty('activityid') != '0'),cellDarkGray: (row.getProperty('returnedRecordsNumber') != '0')}">
<div class="cellOrange" ng-class="{cellRed: (row.getProperty('Impact') == '0'),cellOrange: (row.getProperty('activityid') != '0'), cellBlue: (row.getProperty('Impact') == '2')}"/>
<div class="cellWhite">
<div style="height:60px">
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="(row.getProperty('commentFlag')== true) && (userRole =='ROLE_2') ">
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="(row.getProperty('commentFlag')== true) && (userRole =='ROLE_1') ">
</div>
<div class="inCellData">
<div class="line1" ng-click="openDetails(row,'viewDetail')">
<span class="title1 ng-binding" ng-hide="row.getProperty('planned_typ')== 'NULL'">ORANGE PLANNED MAINTENANCE - </span>
<span class="title2 ng-binding" ng-hide="row.getProperty('deviceid')== 'NULL'">  BLCY810</span>
<!-- <span ng-hide="row.getProperty('myRouterName')== ''"> ||{{row.getProperty('myRouterName')}} ||</span> -->
</div>
<div class="line2">
<span class="title3"/>
<span class="ng-binding" ng-hide="row.getProperty('service_impact')== ''"> 1 - 5 MINS ||</span>
<span class="title3 ng-binding">09/JUN/2017 01:30:00 AM</span>
up to
<span class="title2 ng-binding">09/JUN/2017 03:30:00 AM</span>
|| 
<span class="ng-binding">EQUANT SHARED NETWORK</span>
</div>
<div class="line3">
</div>
<div>
<nav id="cbp-spmenu-s1" class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left cbp-spmenu-open">
<a ng-click="openDetails(row,'viewDetail')">view details</a>
<div class="" ng-show="userRole =='ROLE_1'">
<a class="" ng-show="row.getProperty('internalFlag')=='Y'" ng-click="setUnsetInternal(row)">invisible to customer</a>
<a class="ng-hide" ng-show="row.getProperty('internalFlag')=='Z'" ng-click="row.getProperty('sourcesystem')=='Carrier Changes' && (row.getProperty('urgency')=='EMERGENCY' || row.getProperty('urgency')=='EXPEDITE') ? alertPastDataZEmergency() : alertPastDataZ() ">invisible to customer</a>
<a class="ng-hide" ng-show="row.getProperty('internalFlag')=='N'" ng-click="setUnsetInternal(row)">visible to customer</a>
<a class="ng-hide" ng-show="row.getProperty('internalFlag')=='X' || row.getProperty('internalFlag')=='H'" ng-click="alertPastDataX()">visible to customer</a>
</div>
<!-- Prod Consol Start -->
<a ng-show="userRole =='ROLE_1'" ng-click="openDetails(row, 'comment')">add a comment</a>
<!-- Prod Consol End -->
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: //a[contains(text(), 'add a comment')]   check this xpath

Comment: Thanks Santosh for your response. I am getting below error after execution                      Error Message :Cannot click on element (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: WebElement we1 =GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inCell.ng-scope"));
    Actions action = new Actions (GeneralActionKeywords.driver).contextClick(we1);
    WebElement we2 = GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.id("cbp-spmenu-s1"));
    WebElement we3 = GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cbp-spmenu-s1']/a[2]"));
    action.moveToElement(we2).moveToElement(we3).click().build().perform();    Used this logic to access but it is sometimes invoking mouse right click functionality

Comment: can you give the URL?

Comment: Its not hosted on internet. This link is visible only on mousehover

Comment: what is the element attribute to which you need to do move hover to make comment visible?

Comment: <nav id="cbp-spmenu-s1" class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-left cbp-spmenu-open"> . In firebug am able to see this row getting selected when i mouehover on the div tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to move the mouse using Action class to the element so that Comment link will be visible. Then you have to perform action on that element.

**You can do so like this -**

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'add a comment')]"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elem).click().build().perform();
```

**Hope this helps.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still its not working for me.

Comment: Are you getting any error. If you are, please paste.

Comment: No error  WebElement elem = GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'add a comment')]"));
    System.out.println("HHHHHHHHHHHHH:"+elem.getText());
    Actions action = new Actions(GeneralActionKeywords.driver);
    action.moveToElement(elem).click().build().perform(); when i try to print the element value , nothing is printed

Comment: when i check System.out.println("HHHHHHHHHHHHH:"+elem.isDisplayed()); , I am getting false in my console. This tag gets enabled or visible only on mouse hover

Answer (score 0):

Do mouse hover to the parent element to make the comment visible. Below code might give you some idea.

```
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement("//nav[@id='cbp-spmenu-s1']").perform();

    //Now the comment button will be visible
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'add a comment')]")).click();
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks santosh. Am getting error Cannot click on element . I have added the codes as below                                                             
 Actions action = new Actions(GeneralActionKeywords.driver);
action.moveToElement(GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='cbp-spmenu-s1']"))).perform();
//Now the comment button will be visible GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cbp-spmenu-s1']/a[2]")).click();

Comment: is the comment button becomes visible? What is meant by GeneralActionKeywords.driver

Comment: yes comment button gets visible. I am extending driver from other class. WebElement we1 =GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".inCell.ng-scope"));
Actions action = new Actions (GeneralActionKeywords.driver).contextClick(we1);
WebElement we2 = GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.id("cbp-spmenu-s1"));
action.moveToElement(we2).perform();
WebElement we3 = GeneralActionKeywords.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'add a comment')]"));
action.moveToElement(we2).perform();
action.moveToElement(we3).click().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();

Comment: Try manually making the comment button visible and try to match the comment button with the xpath I have provided... I thing the xpath is getting varied one it become visible...ok

Comment: I didnt understand. Can you provide me some example how to make manually the comment button

Comment: Dude....  The xpath for comment that i have written is based on its attributes which it was not visible. Since it is not working now, i doubt that its attribute is getting changed once its visible.. Can you check the comment's attribute once it has become visible. If i am not clear, open a private chat box

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using below code
WebElement we1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'add a comment')])[1]"));
                    JavascriptExecutor elem = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    elem.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we1);